# How do I find the limit of a function in a function's denominator?

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} \frac {x-1} {2f(x)+4} = 3$, find $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^+} f(x)$

I don't really know how to approach this question, hence I tried to find what f(x) could possibly be, because the numerator approaches 0 as x approaches 1, so there must be an f(x) that can cancels out the numerator such that the limit can be 3 instead of 0. I still don't know how to go about doing it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw you posted the question again because you didn't understand the answer here but then deleted the repost.

So, I hope you may understand my way to answer your question.

First of all, the exercise seems to be in the context of limit laws (adding, multiplying limits etc.) which you most probably are supposed to apply.

Basically you can use these laws to "isolate" $f(x)$, for example, as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*} \lim_{x \to 1} \frac {x-1} {2f(x)+4} = 3
& \Longrightarrow & \lim_{x \to 1} \frac {2f(x)+4} {x-1} = \frac 13 \\
& \stackrel{\lim_{x \to 1} (x-1) = 0}{\Longrightarrow} &  \lim_{x \to 1} (2f(x)+4) = \lim_{x \to 1} \left( \frac {2f(x)+4} {x-1}\cdot (x-1) \right) = \frac 13\cdot 0 = 0 \\
& \Longrightarrow & \lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1} \left(\frac 12\left( (2f(x)+4)-4 \right)\right) = \frac 12(0-4) =-2
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, since $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)= -2$, the right sided limit $\lim_{x \to 1^+} f(x)$ exists as well and is equal to $-2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{x \to 1+0} f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to 1+0} (2f(x)+4)=0, $ since $x-1 \to0$ as $x \to 1+0.$

Thus $\lim_{x \to 1+0} f(x)=-2$ .

Comment: given the comment to the OP's query, your answer seems *premature*.

Comment: i dont quite understand the logic, the limit = 3 is just there to throw us off?

Comment: @chocopie Almost. The exercise is a variation on the theme “is a function is differentiable at a point, then it is continuous at the point”, where you need not know what the derivative is.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator tends to $0$. So if the denominator tends to *nonzero*, the ratio will tend to zero as well.

The only option is that $2f(x)+4$ tends to $0$ (for both $1^+$ and $1^-$).

---

**Advanced result:**

By applying L'Hospital, you can show that $2f'(1)=\dfrac13$.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you don't quite know an answer it can be worth fiddling around with steps you may later need to justify - but that might tell you where you are aiming.

Here you could go $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} \text{ }(x-1)=3\lim_{x\to 1}\left(2f(x)+4\right) $ which makes what is happening obvious.